# regex not yielding desired match

Tags: python, regex

Below is my sample data file.

```
$ cat test.conf
Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI
#Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI
<Directory "/web/htdocs">
    Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI
<Directory "/web/htdocs"> Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI
    RewriteOptions -tester
    Options      -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI
```

I wish to get all the entries (only single lines) using regex that

Begins(start) with the string `"Options"` followed by an of these strings `"Indexes" "FollowSymLinks" "Includes" "ExecCGI"`

I tried the below regex but the problem is that it is yeilding the output `"#Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI"` where the line begins with a hash '#' as well as the line `"<Directory "/web/htdocs"> Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI"` which do not begin with Options on a new line.

Current Output:

```
$ grep -E '^[^\n|#]*[^!Rewrite]Options.*|Indexes|FollowSymLinks|Includes|ExecCGI$' test.conf
Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI
#Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI
    Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI
<Directory "/web/htdocs"> Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI
    Options      -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI
```

Desired Output:

```
Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI
    Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI
    Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI
```

I'm not looking for `grep -v` as a solution but a regex negation instead.

Can you please suggest a regex to meet my requirement ?

Comment: Is it for `python` or `grep`?

Comment: Perhaps like this `^[^\S\r\n]*Options[^\S\r\n]*-(?:Indexes|FollowSymLinks|Includes|ExecCGI)\b.*` https://regex101.com/r/ABGR8r/1

Comment: `[!Rewrite]` matches a single character which is `!` or `R` or `e` etc. If you were trying to do a negative character class, that's `[^Reirtw]` to match a single character which is not `R` or `e` or `i` or `r` or `t` or `w`. If you were trying to say "not `Rewrite`" there is no simple way in traditional `grep` to do that, though if you have `grep -P` you could use negative lookaheads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option using grep could be using a group with an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|` and match zero or more spaces or tabs at the start `[[:blank:]]*`

```
$grep -E '^[[:blank:]]*Options[[:blank:]]+-(Indexes|FollowSymLinks|Includes|ExecCGI)\b' test.conf
```

Output

```
Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI
    Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI
    Options      -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI
```

---

Using Python, you might use

```
^[^\S\r\n]*Options[^\S\r\n]+-(?:Indexes|FollowSymLinks|Includes|ExecCGI)\b.*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\S\r\n]*` Match 0+ times a whitespace char except a newline
- `Options[^\S\r\n]+ Match`Options` followed by matching 1+ times a whitespace char except a newline
- `-` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `Indexes|FollowSymLinks|Includes|ExecCGI` Match 1 of the options
- `)\b` Close group and use a word boundary to prevent the words being part of a larger word
- `.*` Match 0+ times any char except a newline
- `$` Assert end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rN4RUO/1)`

Comment: Amazing answer... Works perfect but can u help explain the python regex especially what that `\b` does?

Comment: @Ashar I have added an explanation.

Comment: We have a dedicated topic about exactly that: [What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)